# Apache -> Ruby locale

Tags: ruby, apache, fastcgi

I've got the following code checking the default encoding for read files (I'm on Linux, Ubuntu 16 x64), just for testing:

```
File.read("/bin/ls").encoding
```

If Apache calls my code through FastCGI then the output is US_ASCII (C locale), but if I run my code manually from anywhere in the system, I get en_US.UTF-8 encoding.

Changing the LANG env variable in /etc/apache2/envvars does not have any effect. Changing the ENV config in /etc/init.d/apache2 doesn't either (after service restart of course). /etc/default/locale is set to en_US.UTF-8. Playing with the virtualhost in my conf file and adding default char sets doesn't help either.

Checking the ENV array when called from Apache is almost empty (only the PATH variable is set), while checking it when run manually is full of variables like LANG etc. So it is obviously an environmental setting problem.

There is an external GEM that I use for my project and it's got a bug when run in a non-unicode environment. I could patch it manually but it's not a good solution because an update will overwrite it.

How could I get Apache to run my code called in a unicode environment?

Comment: Meanwhile I got an answer. Solution is here, it is SOLVED: https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidinitialenv

Comment: If you're using Ruby then FastCGI is the *last* thing you should be using. Packages like [Sinatra](http://www.sinatrarb.com) make writing simple HTTP services super easy and [Passenger](https://www.phusionpassenger.com) is a module that makes Apache httpd (or Nginx!) run Ruby much more efficiently than via FastCGI.

Comment: If you do solve your problem, it's always worth adding a self-answer to help others. The comment there doesn't mark this as "solved", an accepted answer does.

Comment: Passenger is not an option, I've just read it in the doc that multi-threading is not available freely and there are other things that keep me back from considering it at all. Sinatra does not give me any extra help in the code structure either. It is just a tiny simple layer that I can create in a couple of lines of code. No real use here, the amount of abstraction is not decreased enough.

Comment: Older versions of Passenger may have had this problem, but threading support has been in the core for a while now. Sinatra is not just a replacement for a few lines of code, it side-steps the whole world of hurt that CGI is, especially when it comes to parameter parsing. FastCGI is nearly extinct in the Ruby world because it's often the worst possible option for these things, so be careful to evaluate alternatives.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is: https://httpd.apache.org/mod_fcgid/mod/mod_fcgid.html#fcgidinitialenv

```
    edit /etc/apache2/mods-available/fcgid.conf
    FcgidInitialEnv LC_ALL en_US.UTF-8

    service apache2 restart
```